# Can I show certain columns in ls -l command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to show only directories or files which has write permissions. I tried with this:

```
ls -l | cut -f 1,9 | egrep "w"
```

but cut is used with files and I don't want to create one. Moreover, It will show files with that character in the name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The output of `ls -l`is prefixed with the permission structure, with format of **tUUUGGGOOO**, where:

- **t** is the file type indicator (**d** for directories),
- **UUU** are three characters specifying the file owner permissions
- **GGG** are three characters specifying the group permissions
- **OOO** are three characters specifying the others permissions

  The three characters are **rwx** for
- **r** - read
- **w** - write
- **x** - execute
- If a permission is absent, a **-** will be put in its place

**Check Directory Permissions**

Given that, we can construct a regular expression that looks for permission strings that start with **d** and have **w** in the third position (to test that the directory owner has write permission):

`ls -l | egrep -h ^d.w`

To check for group or other permission, just adjust the regular expression:

- check for group write permission: `^d....w`
- check for other write permission: `^d.......w`

**To Check File Permissions**

Replace the **d** in the regular expression with **-**

- owner write permission: `^-.w`
- group write permission: `^-....w`
- other write permission: `^-.......w`

**To Check Either Directory or File**

Put a **.** in the position after the **^**

- owner write permission: `^..w`
- group write permission: `^.....w`
- other write permission: `^........w`

**Regular Expressions**

A good website to test your regular expressions as you construct them is [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To `ls` only directories, use `ls -d`, but it is not very good at selecting only
writable ones.

A better tool here is
[find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html),
which you may use as follows:

```
find /path/to/folder -type d -writable
```

The `-type d` parameter will select only directories, and `-writable` is what
it says.